# How to access nested array of objects element using filter in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, filter

I have been trying to filter the nested array of objects and display the details when the `min_age_limit===18`.

Here is the json :

```json
    "centers": [
    {
            "center_id": 603425,
            "name": "Childrens Hospital",
            "fee_type": "Paid",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "4e687873-5ecc-4086-893e-31a1b450ca3b",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 0,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
            }, {
                "session_id": "54347880-3090-4962-aa56-451fbaca16e1",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 25,
                "min_age_limit": 45,
            }]
    },
    {
            "center_id": 195100,
            "name": "playschool thousandlights",
            "fee_type": "Free",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 15,
                "min_age_limit": 45,
            }, {
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "23-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 19,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
                
            }]
    },
{
            "center_id": 254600,
            "name": "calcicut Hospital",
            "fee_type": "Free",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 15,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
            }, {
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "23-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 19,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
                
            }]
    },
{
            "center_id": 264987,
            "name": "sholings GH",
            "fee_type": "Free",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 15,
                "min_age_limit": 45,
            }, {
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "23-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 19,
                "min_age_limit": 45,
                
            },
{
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "24-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 25,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
                
            }]
    },
{
            "center_id": 254566,
            "name": "greenland Hospital",
            "fee_type": "Free",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 15,
                "min_age_limit": 45,
            }, {
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "23-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 19,
                "min_age_limit": 45,
                
            }]
    }
    ]
```

So to make it clear,
I need to display the session details which has the `min_age_limit===18 along with his center details.`.

I tried this code:

```js
 this.availabityDetails=this.centers.filter(item=>item.sessions.some(age=>age.min_age_limit===18)); 
       console.log(this.availabityDetails);
```

But I am getting the session details of all the center element which has satisfied atleast one condition.
Like,if there is a `min_age_limit=18` in the element with `center_id=195100`,I need to display only that session element details along with the corresponding center details which has satifies this. I need to display only this:
availableDetails should contain this after filtering.

```json
[
    {
            "center_id": 603425,
            "name": "Childrens Hospital",
            "fee_type": "Paid",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "4e687873-5ecc-4086-893e-31a1b450ca3b",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 0,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
            }]
    },
    {
            "center_id": 195100,
            "name": "playschool thousandlights",
            "fee_type": "Free",
            "sessions": [ {
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "23-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 19,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
                
            }]
    },
{
            "center_id": 254600,
            "name": "calcicut Hospital",
            "fee_type": "Free",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 15,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
            }, {
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "23-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 19,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
                
            }]
    },
{
            "center_id": 264987,
            "name": "sholings GH",
            "fee_type": "Free",
            "sessions": [
{
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "24-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 25,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
                
            }]
    }
    ]
```

I need to have the above information in the availableDetails(i.e availableDetails are of type center[]).In above o/p code,centers details are displayed with only the sessions which satisy the condition.i.e session which has min_age_limit =45 are left out . Also In the center ,if there is no session with min_age_limit=18,I dont want that center details in the o/p.
Hope it gives a Clear picture of what I want.
Help me with this code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = {"centers":[{"center_id":603425,"name":"Childrens Hospital","fee_type":"Paid","sessions":[{"session_id":"4e687873-5ecc-4086-893e-31a1b450ca3b","date":"22-05-2021","available_capacity":0,"min_age_limit":18,},{"session_id":"54347880-3090-4962-aa56-451fbaca16e1","date":"22-05-2021","available_capacity":25,"min_age_limit":45,}]},{"center_id":195100,"name":"playschool thousandlights","fee_type":"Free","sessions":[{"session_id":"d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c","date":"22-05-2021","available_capacity":15,"min_age_limit":45,},{"session_id":"7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb","date":"23-05-2021","available_capacity":19,"min_age_limit":18,}]},{"center_id":254600,"name":"calcicut Hospital","fee_type":"Free","sessions":[{"session_id":"d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c","date":"22-05-2021","available_capacity":15,"min_age_limit":18,},{"session_id":"7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb","date":"23-05-2021","available_capacity":19,"min_age_limit":18,}]},{"center_id":264987,"name":"sholings GH","fee_type":"Free","sessions":[{"session_id":"d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c","date":"22-05-2021","available_capacity":15,"min_age_limit":45,},{"session_id":"7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb","date":"23-05-2021","available_capacity":19,"min_age_limit":45,},{"session_id":"7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb","date":"24-05-2021","available_capacity":25,"min_age_limit":18,}]},{"center_id":254566,"name":"greenland Hospital","fee_type":"Free","sessions":[{"session_id":"d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c","date":"22-05-2021","available_capacity":15,"min_age_limit":45,},{"session_id":"7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb","date":"23-05-2021","available_capacity":19,"min_age_limit":45,}]}]}
const res = input.centers
  .map(({sessions, ...r}) => ({
    ...r,
    sessions: sessions.filter(e => e.min_age_limit === 18)
  }))
  .filter(e => e.sessions.length)
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the mistake, I dont need only the child of sessions which satisfies the condition.If the condition is satified, I need to return all the details of that element. In available details ,I also need to have center_id,name and Fee_type along with the session details.

Comment: No bro,this code also displays session details in which min_age_limit=45.I need only the session details which satisifies the condition along with the all the details.

Comment: @VenkateshwarS Is this meet your requirements? If not can you edit your post and shows us actual desired output? Cause I think no1 here knows what you exactly want.

Comment: Sorry for the Confusions .Now I have updated the code.Kindly check and help me .Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much dude.It works really fine .Can you please explain the code!

Comment: This is all you need to know https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
  this.availabityDetails = [].concat.apply([], centers.map(c => c.sessions)).filter(s => s.min_age_limit === 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` method which creates and returns a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
const centers = [
{
        "center_id": 603425,
        "name": "Childrens Hospital",
        "fee_type": "Paid",
        "sessions": [{
            "session_id": "4e687873-5ecc-4086-893e-31a1b450ca3b",
            "date": "22-05-2021",
            "available_capacity": 0,
            "min_age_limit": 18,
        }, {
            "session_id": "54347880-3090-4962-aa56-451fbaca16e1",
            "date": "22-05-2021",
            "available_capacity": 25,
            "min_age_limit": 45,
        }]
},
{
        "center_id": 195100,
        "name": "playschool thousandlights",
        "fee_type": "Free",
        "sessions": [{
            "session_id": "d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c",
            "date": "22-05-2021",
            "available_capacity": 15,
            "min_age_limit": 45,
        }, {
            "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
            "date": "23-05-2021",
            "available_capacity": 19,
            "min_age_limit": 18,
            
        }]
}
];
const sessions = [];
centers.forEach(x => {
   let filtered = x.sessions.find(y => y.min_age_limit === 18);
   let res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filtered));
   res.center_id = x.center_id;
   res.name = x.name;
   res.fee_type = x.fee_type;
   sessions.push(res);
});

console.log(sessions);
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the mistake, I dont need only the child of sessions which satisfies the condition.If the condition is satified, I need to return all the details of that element. In available details ,I also need to have center_id,name and Fee_type along with the session details.

Comment: I updated the code for your request my friend @VenkateshwarS

Comment: Is that what you we're looking for @VenkateshwarS?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` function to list all sessions with the condition `min_age_limit===18`.

```js
const centers = [
    {
            "center_id": 603425,
            "name": "Childrens Hospital",
            "fee_type": "Paid",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "4e687873-5ecc-4086-893e-31a1b450ca3b",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 0,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
            }, {
                "session_id": "54347880-3090-4962-aa56-451fbaca16e1",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 25,
                "min_age_limit": 45,
            }]
    },
    {
            "center_id": 195100,
            "name": "playschool thousandlights",
            "fee_type": "Free",
            "sessions": [{
                "session_id": "d4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c",
                "date": "22-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 15,
                "min_age_limit": 45,
            }, {
                "session_id": "7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb",
                "date": "23-05-2021",
                "available_capacity": 19,
                "min_age_limit": 18,
                
            }]
    }
]
var result = centers.map(item => {
  for (var i = 0, l = item.sessions.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    if (item.sessions[i].min_age_limit === 18) {
      return item.sessions[i]
    }
   }
})
document.write('<pre><ul>' + result.map(o => `<li>${o.session_id}</li>`).join('') + '</ul></pre>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use reduce.

```
this.availabityDetails = this.centers.reduce((acc = [], curr) => {
    if (curr.sessions.length) {curr.sessions = curr.sessions.filter(session => session.min_age_limit === 18)
        acc.push(curr)
    }
    return acc
}, [])
```

.reduce will loop through each element and with each element we will filter session which is min_age_limit === 18 and then push it to accumulator of reduce

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hey sorry for the mistake, I dont need only the child of sessions which satisfies the condition.If the condition is satified, I need to return all the details of that element. In available details ,I also need to have center_id,name and Fee_type along with the session details.

Comment: @venkateshwar Please check the latest code.

Comment: yeah bro this works. I got what I want.But this is also displaying the remaining centers which dont satify the condition with the empty sessions array.Like consider if a certain center id doesnt have min_age_limit=18,then also that center id details is displaying with empty session details.Like if I have 100 array elements.,I have 20 element with 18 age,then i want to display only that 20 elements . but It displays 100 elements with remaining 80 elements displaying empty sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flexible, iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const myData = { centers: [{ center_id: 603425, name: 'Childrens Hospital', fee_type: 'Paid', sessions: [{ session_id: '4e687873-5ecc-4086-893e-31a1b450ca3b', date: '22-05-2021', available_capacity: 0, min_age_limit: 18 }, { session_id: '54347880-3090-4962-aa56-451fbaca16e1', date: '22-05-2021', available_capacity: 25, min_age_limit: 45 }] }, { center_id: 195100, name: 'playschool thousandlights', fee_type: 'Free', sessions: [{ session_id: 'd4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c', date: '22-05-2021', available_capacity: 15, min_age_limit: 45 }, { session_id: '7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb', date: '23-05-2021', available_capacity: 19, min_age_limit: 18 }] }, { center_id: 254600, name: 'calcicut Hospital', fee_type: 'Free', sessions: [{ session_id: 'd4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c', date: '22-05-2021', available_capacity: 15, min_age_limit: 18 }, { session_id: '7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb', date: '23-05-2021', available_capacity: 19, min_age_limit: 18 }] }, { center_id: 264987, name: 'sholings GH', fee_type: 'Free', sessions: [{ session_id: 'd4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c', date: '22-05-2021', available_capacity: 15, min_age_limit: 45 }, { session_id: '7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb', date: '23-05-2021', available_capacity: 19, min_age_limit: 45 }, { session_id: '7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb', date: '24-05-2021', available_capacity: 25, min_age_limit: 18 }] }, { center_id: 254566, name: 'greenland Hospital', fee_type: 'Free', sessions: [{ session_id: 'd4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c', date: '22-05-2021', available_capacity: 15, min_age_limit: 45 }, { session_id: '7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb', date: '23-05-2021', available_capacity: 19, min_age_limit: 45 }] }] };

const extract = objectScan(['centers[*].sessions[*].min_age_limit'], {
  beforeFn: (state) => {
    state.context = new Map();
  },
  afterFn: (state) => {
    state.result = [...state.context.values()];
  },
  breakFn: ({ context, value, parents }) => {
    if (value === 18) {
      const { center_id } = parents[2];
      if (!context.has(center_id)) {
        context.set(center_id, { ...parents[2], sessions: [] });
      }
      context.get(center_id).sessions.push(parents[0]);
    }
  },
  reverse: false
});

console.log(extract(myData));
/* => [ { center_id: 603425, name: 'Childrens Hospital', fee_type: 'Paid', sessions: [ { session_id: '4e687873-5ecc-4086-893e-31a1b450ca3b', date: '22-05-2021', available_capacity: 0, min_age_limit: 18 } ] }, { center_id: 195100, name: 'playschool thousandlights', fee_type: 'Free', sessions: [ { session_id: '7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb', date: '23-05-2021', available_capacity: 19, min_age_limit: 18 } ] }, { center_id: 254600, name: 'calcicut Hospital', fee_type: 'Free', sessions: [ { session_id: 'd4446397-f35e-4140-9778-6af9d8b92a5c', date: '22-05-2021', available_capacity: 15, min_age_limit: 18 }, { session_id: '7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb', date: '23-05-2021', available_capacity: 19, min_age_limit: 18 } ] }, { center_id: 264987, name: 'sholings GH', fee_type: 'Free', sessions: [ { session_id: '7553c7e5-d7ec-456c-af88-0a02756cbdbb', date: '24-05-2021', available_capacity: 25, min_age_limit: 18 } ] } ] */
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)